# How to include left triangle (<) as part of alias command?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm in the process of containerizing my company's existing products and separated out the MySQL database into a different container. To access MySQL server within the main container, I made an alias in ./bashrc so that if a command was:

```
mysql ...
```

It actually runs the following:

```
docker exec -it ${MYSQL_CONTAINER} mysql ...
```

However if the command included a left triangle to add a file, such as:

```
mysql < test.sql
```

I have the alias copy the file and run it, but the bash where the main container lies reads the left triangle as a separate component as opposed to part of the list of arguments.

How can I make my alias take the left triangle as part of the arguments? I'm unable to surround the '< test.sql' part in quotes as existing outside software runs that command in a script and I have to adjust my container to work around it. Thank you.

```
function mysql() {

  $1
  $2
  $3
  $4

  if [[ $1 == "--defaults-file=my.cnf" ]] && [[ ! $2 ]]; then
     docker exec -it ${MYSQL_CONTAINER} mysql $1
  elif [[ $1 == "--defaults-file=my.cnf" ]] && [[ $2 = "<" ]]; then
     #docker cp $3 $(docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' ${MYSQL_CONTAINER}):/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
     #docker exec ${MYSQL_CONTAINER} sh -c "mysql $1 $2 docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/$3"
  elif [[ $1 == "-uroot" ]] && [[ ! $3 ]]; then
     docker exec -it ${MYSQL_CONTAINER} mysql $1 $2
  elif [[ $1 == "-uroot" ]] && [[ $3 = "<" ]]; then
     docker cp $4 $(docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' ${MYSQL_CONTAINER}):/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
     docker exec ${MYSQL_CONTAINER} sh -c "mysql $1 $2 $3 docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/$4"
  else
     docker exec -it ${MYSQL_CONTAINER} mysql $1
  fi

}
```

Comment: What alias? Functions and aliases are very different things.

Comment: ...also, note that `<`, when parsed as shell syntax, is *never* part of an argument list. It's a redirection; redirections aren't arguments (which are passed to the called program); instead, they're instructions to the shell about how to modify the set of active file descriptors *before starting* a program.

Comment: I added this function to my ~/.bashrc to essentially use the command 'mysql' as an alias for running docker exec to access my separate mysql server.

And I'm trying to make the < instead be read as an argument instead of a redirection, is there a way to add it to the argument or make my Linux container ignore redirection when it reads mysql?

Comment: Anyhow, please cut this down to a [mcve] -- provide the *shortest possible* function that produces a *specific problem*, and show the problem with enough details to reproduce: specific arguments used on invocation, error logs, trace with `set -x; mysql ...whatever..., &c in the question itself.

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds. (Note that it's best practice to avoid using code generation to modify the first argument directly after `sh -c`; it would safer to run, say, `docker exec "$MYSQL_CONTAINER" sh -c 'mysql "$@"' _ "$@"` to pass all your function's arguments through to mysql unmodified. Otherwise, you'll have a very bad day whenever those arguments contain quotes, spaces, etc.

Comment: To go back and reemphasize, though: When you run `foo < bar`, `<` is not an argument (it doesn't go in any `$1`/`$2`/`$3`/... slot), and neither is `bar`; instead, they're instructions to the shell to change stdin to be read from `bar` before it starts `foo`. That's completely true for functions (but not always true for aliases, for reasons it's probably not worth getting into right now; moot, though, because you *don't have any* aliases here; your `mysql` is strictly a function, not an alias).

Comment: ...anyhow, it may be that all you need is to add the `-i` argument to whichever case is relevant, so the FD opened to the .sql file you're redirecting is passed through.

Comment: How would you address this problem if Docker weren't involved?  You should use the ordinary `mysql` client in the ordinary way; you're trying to do the Docker equivalent of `ssh root@dbserver mysql ...` to do routine operations, and that's not really a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote or escape the `<` character, otherwise it's processed by the original shell as an input redirection operator:

```
mysql '<' test.sql
```

Then the `<` will be passed literally to your function, and it will pass it to `docker`.

Comment: ...assuming the file actually exists inside the container, that is. If they want to redirect stdin from a file that exists *outside* the container, `mysql < test.sql` is fine as it is (unless maybe they need to pass an extra argument to `docker exec` to have it pass stdin through).

Comment: I don't use docker, so I don't know how they can pass along the outer stdin to the inner instance. It seems like an unlikely thing to do.

Comment: With `-it` (as used in their last case) Docker passes a TTY through properly. I *believe* that just `-i` without `-t` passes stdin through without emulating a TTY, but I haven't used Docker in a while either.

Comment: Anyway, I strongly suspect that he's trying to access a file inside the container, as I think the point of this function is to simplify executing a command within the container.

Comment: I agree that they're trying to execute a command inside the container, but storing data files or SQL scripts in the container would be... unusual. Best practice in the Docker world is to keep them tiny and slim, and if you want to expose data files, to set up bind mounts via the volume mechanism.

Comment: As I said, I don't use docker, I don't know what the usual protocol is.

Comment: @asato, ...by "main Linux container", do you mean the *host*?

Comment: The .sql file is in the main Linux container but simply running something like:

docker exec $MYSQL_CONTAINER mysql < test.sql

Will execute with no errors but then when I access the mysql database, there is no change since it's trying to execute a .sql file that doesn't exist within the mysql container. With the alias, I'm trying to copy the file over to the container and using < there, but I'm struggling with getting past my issue of including < in the original command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not the host of what hosts the containers, I have two containers, one is the primary Linux container that holds the bulk of the application, and then a separate MySQL container. I installed docker into the Linux container so I can run docker commands within it.

Comment: @asato, if you want to feed a file from container A as stdin to something running in container B, that's a case where you really should be keeping the shared content in a volume so it can be mounted directly in both containers. If you *aren't* doing that there's hackery that can happen, like `docker exec -i containerB mysql ... < <(docker exec containerA cat -- /path/to/someFile)`, but that's hackery, and I'd generally avoid it. I would also, personally, not try to use shell redirection syntax for the purpose at all.

Comment: @Barmar, ...btw, some context around the discussion of volumes -- copying content into a Docker container is, when *not* using Docker, done by *creating a new container* as a copy-on-write image of its parent, differing only by virtue of having the extra content added. As such, it's not an operation that it's necessarily good practice to redo every time constantly-shifting content is changed, unless you *want* other components built using that data to be rebuilt afterwards. By contrast, a Docker "volume" is just a mount point for a FS that exists outside the container, and mutable by nature.

Comment: @asato, ...so, the approach I would personally take would be to have a separate function that does the work of attaching stdin to wherever you need it to be. `mysqlWithStdin() { infile=$1; shift; mysql "$@" < <(docker exec otherContainer cat -- "$infile"); }`, for example, and then you can either call `mysql whatever` when you don't want stdin redirected, or `mysqlWithStdin filename.sql whatever` when you do want stdin redirected from `filename.sql` on `otherContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that anyone comes here looking for an answer, I found a way around my question. I was looking for a way for my command line to ignore stdin when using my alias, but since that doesn't seem possible, I instead looked into how to use it.

I am trying to touch a MySQL container from a different container that has connection to my Docker daemon on my host and can run docker commands. For the sake of the project, I can't edit existing commands, so I have to make my main container use mysql commands even though the MySQL server exists on a different container so I had to play around.

```
function mysql() {

  $1
  $2

  if [[ $1 == "--defaults-file=my.cnf" ]]; then
    if [ -t 0 ]; then
       docker exec -it ${MYSQL_CONTAINER} mysql $1
    else
       cat > new_adapter.sql
       cat new_adapter.sql

       docker cp new_adapter.sql $(docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' ${MYSQL_CONTAINER}):/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
       docker exec ${MYSQL_CONTAINER} sh -c "mysql $1 < docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/new_adapter.sql"

       rm -rf new_adapter.sql
    fi
  fi
}
```

With a .sql file on the main container, I can't simply "< example.sql" since it doesn't exist on the MySQL container, so I used the command to copy its contents into a blank .sql file and then copy that over and add it to the database. If there is no stdin, then it simply enters the MySQL server.

Comment: "a way for my command line to ignore stdin when using my alias" -- writing a *function* (repeating myself yet again, functions and aliases are different things, and your code has no aliases at all) that ignores stdin is easy, and if you'd asked we could have told you how to do it. `foo() { { ...; } </dev/null; }` will run `...` with stdin coming from `/dev/null`, ignoring any other redirections.